# Automation Anywhere - How to capture bulk (100s) columns from web screen and share across different subtasks

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I want to capture bulk (100s) columns from the web screen and share across different subtasks. Other than using external files (Excel, CSV, text etc), Any easy way to do this?

[image: 1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vzvM.png]

Comment: What's wrong with Excel, CSV, text etc?

Comment: What's your exact issue? Are you having trouble capturing data or sending it to different subtasks? Also let us know if the subtasks depend on each other for processing or they work on totally different columns?

Answer (score 0):

I think using Variables (or List Variables) is the best way while you don't want to use external things.